# Find all unique combinations of a fixed size to reach a given average range

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

I have a range of integers e.g.

```
big_list = [1, 2, ..., 100]
```

and I need to find all fixed length subsets of the numbers in this range that have an average within k of 50 (like 45-55) for k=5.  e.g. we have a fixed size of 6 with an average of around 50

```
sample = [71, 20, 23, 99, 25, 60]
```

The problem is that the lists have to be unique, with no repeated numbers.

The order doesn't matter, so [71, 20, 23, 99, 25, 60] and [20, 71, 23, 99, 25, 60] is just one combination.

I was thinking of just using itertools to generate all combinations and filtering out based on my criteria. But the run time for that would be really bad as the big list of numbers could range from a size 10 to a size 400.

How can I generate a set of lists with the above criteria

Comment: If your list a list of random numbers or a sequence of numbers? The example makes it look like 1 - 100.

Comment: For my case it's a sequence (if that makes things faster), sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: What counts as *"around 50"*? Is it 45-55 exactly, or just "like" that range?

Comment: As close to 50 as possible ideally, but like maximum distance would be +-5 of the given number (50). I'm trying to generate as many as possible in this scenario and I plan to filter out after I play with the dataset afterwards

Comment: In the most cases it is not real to generate all the possible combination, then filter out some ones, because number of combinations is enormous large for long lists. Perhaps it would better to generate only "good" combinations according to some rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order is trivial to address.

Just make an arrangement with contraints that `i-th` number is greater than `(i-1)-th`. In below algorithm you recurse by incrementing `left` by 1

To get the average in between 45 and 55 consider the recursive formula

```
import math

# left: previous number is left-1
# s: current sum
# d: depth
# c: combination
def fill(left, s, d, c):
  if d == 0:
    return print(c, sum(c)/n)

  # constraint c_sum >= 45*n
  # we look for minimal i such that 
  # sum + i + 100+99+...+(100-(depth-1)+1) >= 45*n
  # sum + i + 100*(d-1) - (d-2)(d-1)/2 >= 45*n
  # i >= 45*n - 100*(d-1) - (d-2)(d-1)/2 - sum
  # 
  # constraint c_sum <= 55*n
  # we look for maximal right such that
  # sum + i + (i+1)+...+(i+(d-1)) <= 55*n
  # sum + (d-1)*i + d(d-1)/2 <= 55*n
  # i <= ( 55*n - d(d-1)/2 - sum )/(d-1)
  minleft = max(left, math.ceil(minBound*n - 100*(d-1) - (d-2)*(d-1)/2 - s))
  if d == 1:
    maxright = min(100, maxBound*n-s)
  else:
    maxright = min(100, math.floor(( maxBound*n - d*(d-1)/2 - s )/(d-1)) )
  for i in range(minleft, maxright+1):
    newsum = s + i
    c[d-1] = i
    fill(i+1, newsum, d-1, c)

n = 6
minBound = 45
maxBound = 55
fill(0, 0, n, [0]*n)
```

---

after further comments, op is not interested at all into combinations as above but in combinations such that no number can appear twice across all combinations

algo can be reduced as the very basic one:

```
n = 300
c = list(range(1, n))
while len(c) >= 6:
  print([c.pop(), c.pop(), c.pop(), c.pop(0), c.pop(0), c.pop(0)])
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way to do this such that the numbers are not repeated?
Example output of the code:
[238, 21, 8, 2, 1, 0] 45.0, 
[239, 21, 8, 2, 1, 0] 45.166666666666664.           

Is there a way to do this such that once a number is used it does not attempt to re-use it?


[239, 21, 8, 2, 1, 0] and then it would no longer generate a combination using 239,21,8,2,1,0?

Comment: But if number can't be repeated, then just take 100&1,99&2,98&3 for first combi, then 97&4,96&5,95&6  etc until you reach about the middle @Helpthisamatuerprogrammer

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what that means

Comment: just take combi [100, 1, 99, 2, 98, 3]. Since you can't use those number anymore, take [97, 4, 96, 5, 95, 6] and so forth @Helpthisamatuerprogrammer

Comment: I guess I'm not too sure how I would be able to translate this into the code provided above

Comment: since you have combi of length 6, that makes 100/6 combi ~16, you may as well write them by hand!

Comment: That's actually what I've been doing haha, I'm trying to automate it for larger lists which is where I'm getting stuck :(, a list of size 300 with 6 leads to 50 combinations,  which is pretty time consuming. (Maybe I didn't ask my question with enough detail - should I re-ask?)

Comment: yeah you could have been more precise, question was properly asked (to me at least) but __misleading__. I have edited my post according to your feedback

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll ask a question with a more accurate description and try to provide better descriptions next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def combo(d, k, c = []):
   if len(c) == 6:
      yield c
   else:
      for i in d:
        _c = (sum(c)+i)/float(len(c)+1)
        if i not in c and (len(c) + 1 < 6 or 50-k <= _c <= 50+k):
            yield from combo(d, k, c+[i])
```

Of course, as @japreiss pointed out, this problem will produce a very bad worst-case time complexity. A possible workaround, however, is to treat `combo` as an iterator pool, and simply access the produced combinations on demand elsewhere in your code. For instance, to access the first 100 results:

```
result = combo(range(1, 100), 5)
for _ in range(100):
   print(next(result))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 67, 98, 99]
[1, 2, 3, 67, 99, 98]
[1, 2, 3, 68, 97, 99]
[1, 2, 3, 68, 98, 99]
[1, 2, 3, 68, 99, 97]
[1, 2, 3, 68, 99, 98]
[1, 2, 3, 69, 96, 99]
[1, 2, 3, 69, 97, 98]
[1, 2, 3, 69, 97, 99]
[1, 2, 3, 69, 98, 97]
...
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way to do this such that the numbers are unique? Once used they cannot be re-used? For example, once [1, 2, 3, 67, 98, 99] is generated, none of those numbers would re-appear?

Comment: you are not giving combination but arrangement